# Received SO Teams domain migration notice on an old email address that I no longer use

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, email

I just received an email that begins with this:

> Date: Tue, 13 Dec 2022 21:14:31 +0800
> From: Stack Overflow Support <support@stackoverflow.com>
> To: iBug <**Email C**>
> Subject: Welcome to the new Stack Overflow for Teams domain (and experience)
>
> Hi there,
>
> You may have noticed Stack Overflow for Teams is on a new domain, *stackoverflowteams.com*. Welcome! ...

However, this email went to **Email C** that I originally signed up for SO with and has been retired years ago. The same email did not come to my active  mailbox, **Email A**.

Here's my profile settings on https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/5958455:

> [image]

Here's my profile settings on `https://stackoverflowteams.com/users/email/settings/<redacted>`:

> [image]

How do I properly update my settings so that I no longer receive emails from Email C?

Comment: I suspect there's a bug here. I've had old emails show up in all kinds of places. It used to show up when trying to create filters with email notifications on stackexchange.com, though I haven't checked that in a couple years at least. They do retain it for some reason, and as evidenced here, it's hooked into several processes.

Comment: @iBug: Would you mind sending us a message via the Contact form with the details of this issue, including the specific email address you received this email under, and which emails were associated with which Teams (i.e. what email addresses A, B, and C are)? That way, we can hopefully identify and resolve the issue. (Please include a link back to this post (or mention it) as well in your contact-form message, so that we know that it's associated with the same case.)

Comment: Thanks, received your email. I'll pass it on to the relevant folks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to a potential bug at some point in the past, your SO Team email values got out to sync. Editing your Team email values today got the correct values into the system on both your end and ours. Your email addresses for your SO Teams are now set correctly per the security settings your Team admins have configured.